# Android showing progress inside Web View for multiple Web Views

Tags: android, webview, android-progressbar

I have a scenario where on a page I can have multiple WebViews that can dynamically load, all at the same time. For example the user may have defined a Google and Yahoo link on the same page. All fine and dandy. What I need though is a way to show that a web view is being loaded without the standard Loading progress dialog since that will freeze the screen. Rather I would like to either show an image in the web view itself saying the web view is loading or have an indicator INSIDE the webview that does not affect the users ability to add data in case the loading of the multiple web views takes a while.

I attempted to load an image in the web view(s) just before loading the real urls, but it seems to either be ignored or immediately overwritten.

thanks!